# 14.04 - How to use integrated CPU graphics with NVIDIA driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cpu, integrated

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and am having some graphics troubles.

Basically, what I want to do is have the NVIDIA driver installed, while still use CPU graphics for the display, and have my NVIDIA card used for CUDA number-crunching. When I install the NVIDIA driver, I am unable to use the CPU graphics for the display (it only lets me use the NVIDIA card for the display). When I use Nouveau, I can use the CPU graphics, but the NVIDIA card is unrecognized by the software. Any help is appreciated, and I'm happy to answer questions.

--Detano